# Issues while Installing Caret

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-caret

All,

When I try to install the library(caret), I get the following error

```
library(caret)
Loading required package: ggplot2
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘pkgconfig’
Error: package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded
```

When ggplot2 is installed separately, it says the following but still not able to load ggplot2

```
package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\b_umair\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpym8OBL\downloaded_packages
```

I am using R version 4.0.2 and have tried majority of the options listed on the internet

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue??

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by "but still not able to load ggplot2". You have installed ggplot2, now if you do library(ggplot2) it should work. then you install caret again?

Comment: When loading the Library ggplot2 I get the following error.                           


Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘pkgconfig’

Comment: seldom encounter this error. have you tried this ? https://community.rstudio.com/t/cant-load-tidyverse/40699/2 basically where are your R libraries installed?

Comment: I think it's basically an issue with rights since I am using a PC where I am not the administrator.

Installed this on a separate machine and no issues whatsoever.